# Kubernetes - What exactly is imperative Vs Declarative

Tags: kubernetes

I am seeing multiple and different explanations for imperative Vs Declarative for Kubernetes - something like Imperative means when we use yaml files to create the resources to describe the state and declarative vice versa.

what is the real and clear difference between these two. I would really appreciate if you can put the group of commands fall under the same - like Create under imperative way etc ..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Imperative" is a command - like "create 42 widgets".

"Declarative" is a statement of the desired end result - like "I want 42 widgets to exist".

Typically, your yaml file will be declarative in nature: it will say that you want 42 widgets to exist.  You'll give that to Kubernetes, and it will execute the steps necessary to end up with having 42 widgets.

"Create" is itself an imperative command, but what you're creating is a Kubernetes cluster.  What the cluster should look like is determined by the declarations in the yaml file.

Comment: can you add few more details with respect to the commands as well as that was the OP was expecting

Comment: It is similar to interpreter v/s compiler.  "Create 1st widget", "Create 2nd Widget" one by one running on command line v/s putting in a for loop & compiling once & running once to create all 42 widgets.

Answer (score 11):

**Imperative**

[Official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/imperative-command/) on Managing Kubernetes Objects Using Imperative Commands.

Kubernetes objects can quickly be created, updated, and deleted directly using imperative commands built into the kubectl command-line tool.

```
kubectl run nginx  --generator=run-pod/v1 --image=nginx

kubectl create service nodeport <myservicename>

kubectl delete pod
```

**Declarartive**

Kubernetes objects can be created, updated, and deleted by storing multiple object configuration files in a directory and using kubectl apply to recursively create and update those objects as needed. This method retains writes made to live objects without merging the changes back into the object configuration files. kubectl diff also gives you a preview of what changes apply will make.

[Official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/) on Declarative Management of Kubernetes Objects Using Configuration Files.

[Official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/) on Declarative Management of Kubernetes Objects Using Kustomize

Define what you want in an yaml file and use `kubectl apply`

```
kubectl apply -f app.yaml

kubectl apply -f <directory>/

kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/simple_deployment.yaml
```

Comment: I feel this should be the acceptable answer, gives a more clear difference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Imperative command means:::  We are not creating any yaml file and directly changing resources like pod service network anything via
Command line so that is imperative command.

Imperative object configuration:::   means we are creating any resources as per our requirement in yaml file where we will remove
default value's which we don’t need everything except required things so in that case this is imperative object configuration AND that is CREATE command..

Declarative object configuration::   We don’t care about anything just we need final output so in simple words we copied
yaml from internet and created a pod where motive is to only create pod/resources So in that case we use APPLY command.